No GFCI/AFCI In House, Identifying Path Forward
I recently purchased a house that lacks a single GFCI or AFCI breaker or outlet.  I spent a day mapping out every receptacle, light, fan, etc.
Now that I understand each branch and what it powers, I'm looking to remedy the issue.  My question is ultimately when to go AF vs GF vs DF (Dual-Function), and which appliances and/or rooms are absolutely necessary.  I'm leaning towards doing entire branches (probably DF breakers), but I can see where getting the first outlet in a branch would make more financial sense.
I know that bathrooms need one or both, as well as outdoor outlets.  I'm sure there are other considerations too like kitchen appliances and clothes washers.
Any guidance is much appreciated!
Edit: I've never used GF/CF breakers before so I don't have a frame of reference. Hoping they are less-prone to nuisance tripping or just generally more reliable.

Any electric close to water moisture must have GFCI protection on new circuits.  It is only very recommended on old circuits.  GFCI protects against ground faults only.  AFCI is mainly for rooms not kitchen/bathroom/outside/near damp areas. It protects against loose/broken connections that spark.

Excellent answer from @man… but I have to step back and ask about your wiring and panel. Is it knob+tube? Has it been messed with over the years? Do you have a dangerous zinsco/fp panel? Maybe you need a more expansive (and, sadly, expensive) strategy.

@AloysiusDefenestrate Hey there, good questions.  The house is only roughly 30 years old.  I guess the county didn't enforce code at the time (outside city limits).  No K&T and the panel is not Zinsco.  Standard, HomeLine, etc.

That’s reassuring.

TL;DR Put GFCI/receptacles in kitchen and bathroom, worry about everything else later
In most, if not all, jurisdictions GFCI and AFCI are required only on new or changed circuits. If the circuits did not require GFCI and/or AFCI when installed then there is nothing that you must do.
It is also important to understand the purpose of these devices:

AFCI - Primarily fire prevention by detecting arcing before it causes a serious problem. This started with bedrooms (because of electric blankets) and has gradually been added to most other rooms in the house. If the wiring, appliances and other devices (such as extension cords and electric blankets) are in good shape then AFCI doesn't have much to do. With the exception of things like rodents chewing through wires, most people will never suddenly have a problem that AFCI will protect them from.
GFCI - This is about direct life safety. While some ground faults can be due to equipment damage or wiring problems, a large part of GFCI protection is about water. Because of that, installing GFCI in key locations - kitchens and bathrooms - is pretty much a no-brainer.

There is also a key difference in how/where these devices are installed:

AFCI - Can be installed as an AFCI/breaker (relatively expensive), AFCI/deadfront (same size as a receptacle but you can't plug anything into it directly) or AFCI/receptacle. But a key piece is that the AFCI must be either at the panel or, if and only if the wiring between the panel and the AFCI is in metal conduit, at or before the first receptacle. Which means for typical non-metallic cable ("Romex") wiring AFCI means AFCI/breaker.
GFCI - Has the same forms as AFCI (GFCI/breaker, GFCI/deadfront, GFCI/receptacle) but with two exceptions it can be installed as GFCI/receptacle and get the full benefit of GFCI protection. The two exceptions are 240V circuits (which have relatively recently been added to the GFCI requirement) and pool, hot tub and similar equipment (which require GFCI protection even if there are no plug-in receptacles involved).

The end result is that the most safety for your money - and something I would highly recommend - is to add GFCI protection to all kitchen countertop receptacle circuits and to all bathroom receptacle circuits. The cost is minimal - some GFCI/receptacles are currently $10 or less (Home Depot, other stores should be similar) and the installation is usually easy. But two things to watch out for:

Multi-Wire Branch Circuits - This gets complicated with GFCI. If you find any receptacles with the hot side split (the metal tab between the screws removed) then it is either an MWBC or a half-switched receptacle, and both of those get complicated with GFCI.
Small Boxes - If you don't have any GFCI/receptacles at all then your wiring is at least a few decades old. Which also means you may find receptacles in boxes barely big enough for a standard receptacle and not nearly large enough for a GFCI/receptacle. Solutions include swapping for a larger box (sometimes easy, sometimes not so easy) or GFCI/breaker or GFCI/deadfront.

The final thing is to understand AFCI and GFCI zones of protection. With a breaker this is easy because everything controlled by the breaker is protected. With a receptacle it gets tricky because a traditional duplex receptacle has two hot screws that are functionally identical and two neutral screws that are functionally identical. With a GFCI/receptacle (or AFCI/receptacle) the top and bottom screws have different functions - one set is line/in, the other set is load/out, and you have to understand how they work to get things connected properly.
When I redid my kitchen > 20 years ago, my electrician put GFCI in the kitchen (required) but also convinced me to install GFCI in the bathrooms. I highly recommend doing the same - kitchen and bathrooms. If you have any other "water" things - hot tub, pool, etc. then definitely GFCI for those as well. Everything else (GFCI for basement, AFCI for lots of rooms, etc.) is simply less critical.
A few more things to consider, thanks to a comment from Aloysius:

Problematic Panels

The advice above assumes you have a reasonable panel in decent condition. If you have a Zinsco, Challenger or Federal Pacific panel or if the panel shows signs of damage (e.g., burn marks), is significantly miswired (e.g., multiple wires (except grounds) under a single screw) or has improper breakers (breakers from one brand installed in a panel from another brand, with certain legitimate exceptions) then straightening out the panel takes priority. We can mostly get an idea of these issues with pictures of the panel (with cover off, carefully, so we can see the actual wiring) and label (if it hasn't faded away or fallen off over the years).

Problematic Wiring

The biggest concern is knob and tube. This is a very old wiring type. It is safe if in good condition and used properly. But working on it is a mostly lost art, so if you have knob and tube wiring (basically separate wires instead of wires together in cable or conduit) then making any changes, upgrades, etc. can be much trickier. (New comment indicates this is much newer than the knob & tube era.)
The other concern is aluminum wiring. Aluminum is fine for feeders and, in most places, for large wires. But 15A, 20A and 30A circuits are usually copper so the devices (receptacles, light fixtures, etc.) for smaller circuits are often only rated for use with copper, not aluminum. (Even some larger devices such as Tesla Wall Chargers are copper only.) If you have aluminum wiring on branch circuits then you need to be careful that any replacement devices are properly rated and installed and it is worth checking existing devices to make sure they are OK for use with aluminum wiring. (Based on comment, house ~ 30 years old, which should be well past the aluminum wire era.)

Many thanks. I won't lie - I've read this probably 10 times over.  Lots of good information here and I greatly appreciate you sharing with me.
